# Non-symmetric orthogonal direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Are there an infinite dimensional linear space $U$ (the field of scalars is insignificant, but the real number field would be welcome) and a symmetric bilinear functional $B$ such that:
if $U=V \oplus W$ is any orthogonal direct sum, then the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ are strictly different (finite or infinite) cardinal numbers. Here, orthogonality means that $B(V,W)=0$.

Comment: If $E \subset U$ is an orthogonal basis then since $U$ is infinite dimensional we can parititon $E$ into two infinite subsets with the same cardinality.

Comment: Well, if the orthogonal basis would always exists. But does it? My guess is it doesn´t since the space is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Given Zorn's Lemma, we can prove every vector space has a basis, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Proof_that_every_vector_space_has_a_basis I think it's straightforward to modify the proof, instead starting with all subsets of linearly independent vectors that are pairwise orthogonal. But I could be missing something!

Comment: Zorn´s Lemma assures the existence of a maximal pairwise orthogonal linearly independent set. But this set could be infinite and I don´t see any way to find another orthogonal element out of its linear span. So, I am pretty sure that the answer to my initial quetion is yes. If only I could find an example...